# Independence of two limit distributions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, probability-limit-theorems

**Background**

Suppose that $X_n\to X$ and $Y_n\to Y$ in distribution. If $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are mutually uncorrelated but not independent, what we can say about $X$ and $Y$ knowing that $X_n\sim Y_n$, $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$?

In my particular case I have that $X_n\to X\sim \Gamma(1/2,1)$ and similarly $Y_n\to Y\sim\Gamma(1/2,1)$, and experimentally I've seen (by using Monte Carlo simulation) that $X+Y\sim\Gamma(1,1)\sim Exp(1)$, **as they were independent**.

**Question**

There exists a concept of asymptotic independence that I can use to prove that indeed the limit distributions $X$ and $Y$ are independent? What conditions $X_n$ and $Y_n$ should satisfy? Thank you in advance.

Comment: In general we can't say anything about the independence of the limits (for example just take $X_n = X$ and $Y_n = Y$). Maybe the assumption that $X,Y$ and $X+Y$ are Gamma distributed could help though. How do you get the convergence in distribution in the first case? Is it something you prove or just an assumption?

Comment: Convergence in distribution is unique with respect to measures, but not unique with respect to random variables (i.e. there are many random variables with the same distribution). In particular, asking about the distribution of $(X,Y)$ is meaningless knowing only that $X_n \to X$ and $Y_n \to Y$ in distribution (you can always change $X$ to $X'$ and $Y$ to $Y'$ with $X \sim X', Y \sim Y'$ and you still have $X_n \to X', Y_n \to Y'$ in distribution, but the distribution of $(X',Y')$ can differ from that of $(X,Y)$).

Comment: @Michh the convergence in distribution of $X_n\to X$ and $Y_n\to Y$ is something I manage to prove, while the fact that $X+Y$ is distributed as $X$ and $Y$ were indipendent is an observation I made thanks to a computer simulation.

Comment: @DominikKutek Ok, I understand you.. and what about the concept of asymptotic indipendence of $X_n$ and $Y_n$ as $n\to\infty$? I have read something online but I'm not really sure how to proceed and where I have to look.

Comment: My suggestion then would be to try to prove joint convergence. For example, if you're working with characteristic functions it is enough to show that $\mathbb{E}[e^{itX_n +isY_n}] \to (1-it)^{-1/2}(1-is)^{-1/2}$.

Comment: @Michh is it necessary to take $t,s$ (eventually different)? May I take $t=s$ to prove the same? Of course it will be more simple.. thank you in advance!

Comment: Taking $t$ and $s$ amounts to looking at the convergence of $(X_n,Y_n)$ (this is what you want in order to show asymptotic independence) whereas $t=s$ is only looking at the convergence of $X_n+Y_n$. Hope that helps

Comment: @Michh , yeah I understand now. Thank you!